# Should it be "German society" or "the German society"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

This is a line I came across in someone's bio. Apparently the author is not a native speaker of English.

> Since 2005 I have extended my research on education to **the German society**.

I am under the impression that an article should not be used when referring to a country's society collectively. Google search results show that most journalistic writings do not use the definite article before a nation's collective public, i.e. "**German society**", "**Chinese society**", "**Japanese society**". There are some search results on Google Books and Google Scholar that have the definite article before a nation's society, but I am not sure they have been authored by native speakers of English.

Should there be the definite article in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

You would use **The** German Society only to refer to a specific organization (like a school's German language club that called itself this) or a specific period of German society ("The German society of the 1920s").

Otherwise, it would just be "German society."

Answer (score 1):

**No**
Just as you might say

> Since 2005 I have extended my research on education to **include** German society.

You do not need the definite article unless it is a specific portion

> Since 2005 I have extended my research on education to **include the** German society of the 1940's.